# How to do conditional imports without custom webpack configuration?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, webpack, electron

We have a project that builds for both Cordova and Electron from a single codebase, so it needs to import Node APIs and Node-specific modules when in Electron and ignore them in Cordova. Up to now we've been using a custom webpack configuration to accomplish this, passing an environment variable to tell it whether to treat the Node stuff as `externals` (Cordova) or `require` it (Electron). However, now that we're on Angular 9, the builder needed to run a custom webpack (`@angular-builders/custom-webpack`) conflicts with the Ionic dev server builder (`@ionic/angular-toolkit:cordova-serve`), and integrating them looks painful. How can we do this without a custom webpack script?

Answer (score -1):

I finally discovered that Webpack provides `__non_webpack_require__()`, which just transforms into a runtime `require`. This made it possible to write a best-effort import that maintains type safety with TypeScript:

```
declare function __non_webpack_require__(path: string): any;

import * as node_hid_typeonly from 'node-hid';
let node_hid: typeof node_hid_typeonly;
try { node_hid = __non_webpack_require__('node-hid'); } catch { }
```

This does the following:

1. Tells TypeScript that `__non_webpack_require__()` exists
2. Imports `node-hid` for use in type annotations only (if an import is only used for type information, `tsc` elides it)
3. Does a best-effort import of `node-hid` into a variable declared with the appropriate type

You end up being able to write:

```
private device: node_hid_typeonly.HID;
```

and later,

```
this.device = new node_hid.HID(path);
```

We also reuse some of this code in a non-webpack project, which I accommodated with:

```
global['__non_webpack_require__'] = require;
```

in `index.ts` before importing anything that would have `__non_webpack_require__`.

Comment: Creating a global variable, assuming require exists, and relying on implementation details of Webpack may work fine for you but it is hardly something to promote. There are plenty of ways to conditionally import things

Comment: `__non_webpack_require__` is Webpack public API, not an implementation detail. I'm interested in other strategies though...what would you recommend? This is library code (used internally) that needs to run in Electron and Cordova with Angular+webpack, as well as under node with neither of those.